use of "instead"
I want to understand the grammatical function of the word "instead" as it is used in the following sentence:

Yet, they themselves survive without apology, with, instead, their simple claims and complex colors.

This is a quote from a passage in the English section of a past ACT test. It's difficult to explain the comma pattern to students, although intuitively it sounds right (to my ear at least). In the sentence quoted above, "instead" doesn't seem to be a conjunctive adverb. Is "instead" here best understood as an "interrupter"? Help!

Heh, somebody was paid per comma! There's nothing unusual about grammatical function there; just syntax. It works the same as if "instead" were at the end of the sentence.

No, the word is used here as an appositive, an interrupting element by definition. But it works as an adverb on survive, sort of "They survive instead with ... colors."

The commas mark instead as a nonessential part of the sentence. But as a part of speech, it’s still an adverb.
